# Why can i pass in unlimited argument as injection in constructor of magento2?

Tags: magento2, php, dependency-injection, methods

In my understanding, argument passed to a function/method are strictly mapped to your function call, and the arguments must be arranged in correct order to map what you pass in your function call.

```
e.g. function test(a,b){
     return ....
}
$result = test(myValue1, myValue2);
```

But in magento2, when we override a class, we can inject more & more argument as we like ,
e.g.

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magestore\Bannerslider\Model\ResourceModel\Banner\CollectionFactory $bannerCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
```

After override, one more argument is injected:

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magestore\Bannerslider\Model\ResourceModel\Banner\CollectionFactory $bannerCollectionFactory,
        \Magestore\Bannerslider\Model\SliderFactory $sliderFactory,
        SliderModel $slider,
        array $data = []
    ) {
```

Why php could accept this changes? Couldn't it crash the method call as the number of arguments are not the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that Magento instantiates classes dynamically.

From `\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory`:

```
protected function createObject($type, $args)
{
    return new $type(...array_values($args));
}
```

This method instantiates a class where `$type` is the class to be instantiated and `$args` is an array of arguments. This allows for flexibility in regards to the arguments passed to any given class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 has a system which takes the type hints from the constructor and actually generates the objects which then get injected at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> Why PHP could accept this changes?

- in object oriented programming constructor is not part of an interface
- it does not make sense to not allow it because inheritance, in this case, doesn't make sense at all

> Couldn't it crash the method call as the number of arguments are not the same?

No, is would not